# Get all nested types of a type in Swift (as metatypes references)

Tags: swift, dynamic, reflection, runtime, introspection

I have some nested classes definition in Swift, like:

```
class Animal {
    class Mammal {
        class Tiger {}
        class Wolf {}
    }
    class Bird {} 
}
```

Is it possible to introspect this hierarchy to automatically get an array of metatypes from it, like this, but in runtime:

```
[
    Animal.self,
    Animal.Mammal.self,
    Animal.Mammal.Tiger.self,
    Animal.Mammal.Wolf.self,
    Animal.Bird.self,
]
```

Comment: Why do you need this kind of array of metatypes at runtime, what kind of problem you are solving?

Comment: @Torongo it might be an instances actually instead of metatypes. I just need to process all those instances of every class in a batch (they're all of the same supertype/protocol), but I don't have the instances. And there're a lot of them, so I don't want to write this array by myself.